# Net-SSH/Capistrano problem: "Could not parse PKey: no start line"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssh, capistrano, openssh, net-ssh

For years I've been deploying my Rails 3.2.13 app successfully using Capistrano. But just today I ran into the dreaded `ArgumentError: Could not parse PKey: no start line` when connecting to the server.

From other posts I gather this is actually an issue with the `net-ssh` gem, which Capistrano uses to make the connection. Apparently older versions of `net-ssh` aren't compatible with the key files created by more recent versions of OpenSSH. (See [here](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/101) and [here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/286) for example.)

This diagnosis is supported by (a) the fact I can still SSH into my server from the command line, and (b) the following little `irb` session:

```
irb(main):006:0> require 'net/ssh'
=> true
irb(main):007:0> Net::SSH::KeyFactory.load_private_key('~/.ssh/id_rsa')
ArgumentError: Could not parse PKey: no start line
```

I guess I updated my private key file recently when I changed my password, and now it's incompatible with my version of `net-ssh` (v2.7.0).

I can't upgrade `net-ssh` since I'm stuck with Ruby 1.9.3.

Is there maybe a way to get back to an old/compatible version of the private key file? Or some other solution perhaps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved it by running:

```
ssh-keygen -p -m PEM
```

and then following the prompts to "reset" the password for my private key.

Adding the `-m PEM` option gave me back the old-style `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file I needed for compatibility with my old version of `net-ssh`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Stuck with ruby 1.9.3, too.